# Numba njit not working for numpy based function

Tags: python, numba, jit

I have this correlate function:

```
@numba.njit
def correlate(self, mat, filter, type) -> np.ndarray:
    def apply_filter(mat, filter, point):
        point = (max(0, point[0]), max(0, point[1]))
        end_point = (min(mat.shape[0], point[0] + filter.shape[0]), 
                     min(mat.shape[1], point[1] + filter.shape[1]))
        area = mat[point[0]:end_point[0], point[1]:end_point[1]]
        if filter.shape != area.shape:
            # filter = np.resize(filter, area.shape)
            filter = filter[area.shape[0] - 1, area.shape[1] - 1]
        result = np.multiply(area, filter)
        result = np.sum(result)
        return result

    if type == "valid":
        new_mat_size = (mat.shape[0] - filter.shape[0] + 1, mat.shape[1] - filter.shape[0] + 1)
    elif type == "full":
        new_mat_size = (mat.shape[0] + filter.shape[0] - 1, mat.shape[1] + filter.shape[1] - 1)

    f_mat = np.zeros(new_mat_size)
    for x in range(new_mat_size[0]):
        for y in range(new_mat_size[1]):
            if type == "valid":
                f_mat[x, y] = apply_filter(mat, filter, (x, y))
            elif type == "full":
                f_mat[x, y] = apply_filter(mat, filter, (x - filter.shape[0] + 1, y - filter.shape[1] + 1))
    return f_mat
```

It works fine without the `@numba.njit` .
But if I were to leave it there this error comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eiiri\Desktop\NeuralNetwork\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    net.train(X, Y, epochs=3, lr=0.01)
  File "C:\Users\eiiri\Desktop\NeuralNetwork\neuralG.py", line 36, in train
    output = self.forwardProp(X)
  File "C:\Users\eiiri\Desktop\NeuralNetwork\neuralG.py", line 20, in forwardProp
    output = layer.forwardProp(output)
  File "C:\Users\eiiri\Desktop\NeuralNetwork\neuralgNeccessities\Layers\convolutional_layer.py", line 20, in forwardProp
    output[k] += self.correlate(input[i], self.kernels[k][i], "valid")
  File "C:\Users\eiiri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\eiiri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
←[1m←[1mCannot unify float64 and array(float64, 2d, C) for 'closure__locals__apply_filter_v3_filter_2.2', defined at C:\Users\eiiri\Desktop\NeuralNetwork\neuralgNeccessities\Layers\convolutional_layer.py (49)
←[1m
File "neuralgNeccessities\Layers\convolutional_layer.py", line 49:←[0m
←[1m        def apply_filter(mat, filter, point):
            <source elided>
                filter = filter[area.shape[0] - 1, area.shape[1] - 1]
←[1m            result = np.multiply(area, filter)
←[0m            ←[1m^←[0m←[0m
←[0m
←[0m←[1mDuring: typing of assignment at C:\Users\eiiri\Desktop\NeuralNetwork\neuralgNeccessities\Layers\convolutional_layer.py (49)←[0m
←[1m
File "neuralgNeccessities\Layers\convolutional_layer.py", line 49:←[0m
←[1m        def apply_filter(mat, filter, point):
            <source elided>
                filter = filter[area.shape[0] - 1, area.shape[1] - 1]
←[1m            result = np.multiply(area, filter)
←[0m            ←[1m^←[0m←[0m

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: ←[1mCannot determine Numba type of <class 'neuralgNeccessities.Layers.convolutional_layer.Convolutional'>←[0m
```

I can't quite figure out, what causes the error here.
Im new to numba and JIT in general and would be glad for any help. 
Kind Regards 
-Eirik

Comment: Numba basically say "*Cannot determine Numba type of class `neuralgNeccessities.Layers.convolutional_layer.Convolutional`*" because Numba does not support CPython types nor arbitrary custom user type. Your type needs to be a Numpy one or a native one or a JITed class (highly experimental) with type annotation. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is critical because of type inference. I also advise you to read the doc because such information are (weakly) mentioned. See: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/index.html .

Comment: Okay, what should I change in the code then?

Comment: Use Numpy types or native ones (I do not advise you to use JITed class yet).